# How can I make my text box follow the GUI

Tags: game-maker

I have a text box element in game on my gui which is loaded in after the user enters the room.

```
goto_room = asset_get_index(target_room);
room_goto(goto_room);

//Initiate a player object on this room
with(instance_create(target_x, target_y, obj_Player)) {
     name = other.name;
}
with(instance_create(15, window_get_height()-15, txt_ChatBox)) {
     image_xscale = string_width("g") * 99;
}
```

the object hierarchy is:
txt_ChatBox>gui_textBox_base>ui_focus_base>ui_base

this is the draw event where everything happens

```
Draw GUI:
/// Draws the text box
if not uiVisible exit;  //if not visible, don't draw it!

x = view_xview[0] + 15;
y = (view_hview[0] - 15) + view_yview[0];

if isFocused {
    draw_rectangle(posX, posY, posX + (16 * image_xscale), posY + (16 * image_yscale), 2);
}

if(string_length(text) > 0 || isFocused) {
    draw_text(posX + 3, posY, string(text));
} else {
    draw_text(posX + 3, posY, string(placeholder));
}
```

In game it works but it also adds part of it to the map like this
[image]

EDIT: something new I have found is that the one on the map is the physical instance of the control but all the drawing for text happens in the drawGUI call. I.e. the on click handler that give it focus only works on the on map one.

I made the map/physical one move at the start of the drawGUI to where I wanted it to be but it was off from the gui one by a bit during scrolling which could be smoothed out but I don't think that is the right answer (see updated code above).

I have a feeling I need to say please be part of the view rather than part of the map right??

Comment: If you draw in `Draw GUI` event then you not need use `view_xview[0] / view_yview[0]` because GUI layer have own coords system (see `display_set_gui_size()` and `display_set_gui_maximise()`). And if you use `Draw GUI` event, you need remember that `Draw` event also will work (so, if object have a sprite then it will be drawed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw something fixed on the screen, you have two common options:

**The Draw Event**

This Event will draw Sprites, Pixels, Lines, etc *within* the Room. In order to make this appear in the same place, you'll need to offset whatever you're drawing with `view_xview` and `view_yview`. Note that both of these are arrays, so you should use whichever view you're using for your main display. If that made no sense to you, then just use `view_xview[0]` and `view_yview[0]`.

This approach has some drawbacks. If you scale or rotate the view, whatever you've drawn will scale and rotate too. Seeing as that's probably not what you want, then I recommend the other approach.

**The Draw GUI Event**

Rather than drawing within the Room, this Event will draw *on the screen*. As such, you should use coordinates that match this. To determine the width and height of your display, use the `display_get_width()` and `display_get_height()` methods.

This is by far the preferred method, as you'll be drawing to the screen, rather than within the room. This method also supports view scaling and rotation, as you're drawing to the screen directly.

Comment: Basically this is the answer but in order to negate the default draw event of the object(apparently because of the sprite it has), I have a draw event with a blank code block and draw_self() does the work in the draw gui event

Comment: I typically have dedicated objects for drawing GUI elements. It shouldn't be the responsibility of the player object (or whatever object) to draw GUI elements. I often use either a `gui_` prefix for objects that just draw GUI things, or I leave it to a controller (prefixed with `ctrl_`).